# Changed Swappiness to 5 but no effect, Ubuntu still swaps when 60% ram is used

Tags: 18.04, ram, swap

In sysctl.conf file I have put vm.swappiness = 10 at the end of the file and saved it as root. And then rebooted my pc; But even then Ubuntu swaps when 60% of my ram is used when it is actually supposed to swap when ram is 95% used.

There are other things I have tried as well, like:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=5
```

and

```
echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

But these don't work well.

Please help me set swappiness such that swap will only be used when 95% of my ram has been used.

Comment: Please show me `free -h` and tell me what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: free -h output

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.5G        2.2G        3.1G        425M        2.2G        4.7G
Swap:           15G          0B         15G `


I want swap to be used only when 95% of my ram is used.

Comment: vm.swappiness either favors RAM or favors swap, not so much a percentage thing. With only 8G RAM, vm.swappiness=5 is the wrong thing to do. Why do you want swap to be used when 95% of your RAM is used? That's not a good goal.

Comment: @heynnema, because in middle of my work, when 60% of my ram is used, my system starts swapping which in turn results in my system becoming very laggy and there are even cases that it freezes for a moment. This is very troublesome for me

Comment: What apps do you normally run? You may need more RAM.

Comment: @heynnema, I normally use vs code, chrome, postman for work purposes.
It started like this, everything was running smoothly, but ever since I installed Android Studio and started working with React Native this trouble started. It happens even when I don't run React Native Code

Comment: You need more RAM. Add memory in matched pairs, so if you have 1 8G stick now, get another 8G stick. If you have 2 4G sticks, get 2 8G sticks.

Comment: @heynnema I know three other people who has the same ram as I do but they are not facing this problem :/

Comment: Load up your various apps. In `terminal` type `top`. Then hit "m" twice. Then "f", arrow down to MEM%, hit "s", then "q". Take a screenshot, edit it into your question, and let me know when you're done.

Comment: I have the same problem but in my case heavy swaping starts at 85%. `vm.swappiness` just not working.